# Copy folders and exclude folder

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a code that copy a folder to another location through textboxes. `Textbox1` where the user can specify which folder to copy and `textbox2` that the user can browse for a destination folder.

If `Textbox1` is the path to "My documents" an error occur saying:

> Access to path `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Documents\My Music` is denied.

"My Music" is a hidden folder in "My document" that is checked as "hide protected operating system files" by windows 7. I am using Visual Studio 2005 and new in VB.net, can anybody take a look at this code and tell me a way to exclude folders to copy?

```
Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    Dim fs As Object = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim sFolderpath As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim sourceFolderName As String = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFolderpath)

    Dim strDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim dFolderpath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(TextBox6.Text, strDate)
    fs.createfolder(dFolderpath)
    dFolderpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dFolderpath, sourceFolderName)
    fs.createfolder(dFolderpath)

    fs.copyfolder(sFolderpath, dFolderpath)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest splitting the problem into 4 subs. Firstly two subs to allow users to select a folder they desire for source and destination. The a button click event that starts the copying and finally a sub that actually handles the copying.

Try this on for size:

```
    Dim CopyFromPath As String
Dim CopyToPath As String

Private Sub TextBox1_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.MouseClick
    Dim fldbroser1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fldbroser1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyMusic
    fldbroser1.ShowDialog()
    CopyFromPath = fldbroser1.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_MouseClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.MouseClick
    Dim fldbroser1 As New FolderBrowserDialog
    fldbroser1.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer
    fldbroser1.ShowDialog()
    CopyToPath = fldbroser1.SelectedPath
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    CopyAllFiles(CopyFromPath, CopyToPath)
End Sub

Private Sub CopyAllFiles(ByVal CopyFromPath As String, ByVal CopyToPath As String)
    If Not Directory.Exists(CopyToPath) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(CopyToPath)
    End If

    For Each filee As String In Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(CopyFromPath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(CopyToPath, Path.GetFileName(filee))
        File.Copy(filee, dest)
    Next

    For Each folder As String In Directory.GetDirectories(Path.GetDirectoryName(CopyFromPath))
        Dim dest As String = Path.Combine(CopyToPath, Path.GetFileName(folder))
        CopyAllFiles(folder, dest)
    Next
End Sub
```

You will need to import System.IO for this to work. Fell free to ask any questions if you have trouble with the code. Good luck learning VB, it can be annoying at times but it's pretty useful.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to implement it to my code. Maybe you know why windows 7 have for standard "My Music", "My Pictures" and "My Videos" as hidden folders in "My Documents"?

Comment: I can't see any reason that a users own my documents/music etc. folders would be hidden from them. If you are trying to access the folders of a different user to the one whom is running the code this may be the issue. I imagine there is a way around this with security permissions but if the code I've provided works it should be reasonably slick and user friendly.

Comment: Thank you for you help "FraserOfSmeg" but I need to stick with the original code. Please have a look at my other question that will explain a little bit more about the problem.